# How can I exclude a property from a lombok builder only if the property is null

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have a user model class that looks like:

```
@JsonSerialize
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder
public class User {
    @Default
    String _dn = BASE_USER_DN;
    @Default
    String[] objectClass = {"top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson", "companyUser"};
    @Default
    String[] cn = {"user205"};
    @Default
    String[] sn = {"Dynamic2"};
    @Default
    String[] username = {"LindaDynamic2"};
}
```

Now I'd like to generate a user object that omits null fields so:

```
userBody = User.builder().cn(null).build();
```

would create an object without a cn property or if I added a field without a default and it wasn't set on the builder it would be omitted.

Is this possible?

Comment: you want to exclude during serialization ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add following annotation if you want to exclude during serialization:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: so simple and yet so brilliant

Comment: Note: this is a `jackson` annotation. It is unrelated to Lombok. It can be added at the class level, method level, field level, etc.

Comment: Way better than using that old `@JsonIgnore` annotation, right?