# Lombok builder - ignore objects with null value

Tags: java, lombok

My first steps with Lombok @Builder.

So I receive ExternalVehicles object from external service (10 cars inside).

```
public class CarConverter {

    private Car convertToCar(ExternalVehicles vehicles) {

        return Car.builder()
                .plateNumber(getPlateNumberFromObjectNestedInExternalVehicles("plateNumber"))
                .brand(getBrandFromObjectNestedInExternalVehicles("brand"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

For one car, the null is received in plateNumber field.
So I would like to ignore this car and convert only 9.

How can I do this?

Comment: can this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774417/how-can-i-exclude-a-property-from-a-lombok-builder-only-if-the-property-is-null

Comment: Sounds like something that should be done by filtering objects in `ExternalVehicles`, not by a builder.

Comment: Thanks @Chaosfire I will do it in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to mention:

1. you can filter the cars before the convertion

```
externalCars.stream()
     .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull() && isCarValid())
     .map(CarConverter::convertToCar)
     .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

2. you can do some checks within your conversion method and filter afterwards

```
public class CarConverter {

    private Car convertToCar(ExternalVehicles vehicles) {
        if (vehicles == null || getPlateNumberFromObjectNestedInExternalVehicles("plateNumber") == null)
            return null

        return Car.builder()
                .plateNumber(getPlateNumberFromObjectNestedInExternalVehicles("plateNumber"))
                .brand(getBrandFromObjectNestedInExternalVehicles("brand"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

and then filter before the collection

```
externalCars.stream()
     .map(CarConverter::convertToCar)
     .filter(car -> Objects.nonNull())
     .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

In my experience, this leads to less `NullPointerExceptions`

Just for completion, there are also way,to fail the `.build()` method as seen here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654258/1538176